# Did flutter_driver library able to Test Website (which built by flutter)

Tags: flutter, testing, automated-tests, flutter-web, flutter-test

I would like to create an automated test for the Website which was created by flutter but I found out that we cannot inspect the element on the website so anyways that I can test it. Please help